# How to create softlink for a file /var/log/messages on /root/Desktop with same name using ln command

Tags: linux, symlink, syntax

Which one should be the target and which one be the link name?

Update 1: I am logged in as super user, and I also got to know to access root folder using GUI.

Comment: Why `/root/Desktop`?  Are you running logged in as root? That really not a good idea.

Comment: @frazzerk You are not making sense. Why do you want the shortcut to be on the root user's desktop if you are not logged in using the root login (OP is getting permission denied while trying to access the root directory using the GUI). Please clarify what you want **clearly** with an [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/396679/edit)

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate of [Direction of a symlink](https://superuser.com/q/522287/354511)

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, use the checkmark next to it. You may need to merge your accounts, after registering one.

Answer (score 2):

Almost the first line of `man ln` will tell you the answer to this:

> ```
> ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
> ```

It's the same order as `mv` and `cp`: source then destination. So in your case you would use something like

```
cd /root/Desktop
ln -s /var/log/messages messages
```

The `-s` parameter instructs `ln` to create a soft link rather than the default hard link.

It's possible to omit the last argument to `ln` in which case the source file name will be reused

```
cd /root/Desktop
ln -s /var/log/messages
```

Notice that in both cases I have changed to the destination directory. This ensures that `ln -s` with relative paths will work correctly and as expected. In this situation we're using an absolute path (it begins with `/`) but it's a good practice to start using.